# PROC DTREE, PROC TREE, PROC SPLIT in SAS

Tags: sas

Is it possible to generate a simple tree with values at each node in SAS? I'm looking to create something simple like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in doing something similar a while back - printing a folder tree to the output area. I wasn't able to find a dedicated SAS proc that would work this way. The only method I know of that would allow you to create something like this (with quite a lot of effort) would be to write a macro to generate all the lines and captions in an annotation dataset, and then generate an image from it using proc ganno or proc gslide. See [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#annodatachap.htm) for further details on using annotation datasets.